# Função infixa para pós-fixa

Tags: c, stack

Estou fazendo um código que converte uma função infixa para a notação pós-fixa, exemplo: 4+2 para 42+. E não estou conseguindo fazer a prioridade dos elementos, por exemplo, quando faço a expressão 4+2*8, espero o resultado 428*+, mas está imprimindo 42*8+, por conta da prioridade matemática que está errada em meu código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define max  1000
    #include <stdbool.h>

    typedef struct key{
        char tipo;
    }TipoItem;

    typedef struct pilha{
        TipoItem item[max];
        int topo;
    }Pilha;
    
    void criapilha(Pilha *pi){
        pi->topo=0;
    }
    
    void empilha(Pilha *pi,TipoItem c){
        if(pi->topo == max){
            printf("Pilha cheia.\n");
            return;
        }
        else{
            pi->item[pi->topo] = c;
            pi->topo++;
        }
    }
    
    int vazia(Pilha pi){
        return (pi.topo == 0);
    }
    
    void desempilha(Pilha *pi,TipoItem *x){
        char c;
        if(vazia(*pi)){
                //printf("Pilha vazia.\n");
            return;
        }
        else{
            *x = pi->item[pi->topo-1];
            pi->topo--;
        }
    }
    
    void printa(Pilha *pi){
        if(pi->topo == 0){
            printf("Pilha vazia.\n");
            return;
        }
        else{
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<pi->topo;i++){
                printf("%c ",pi->item[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    int prioridade(char a, char b){
        if('a' <= 'c')
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    int main(){
        Pilha pi; criapilha(&pi);
        TipoItem elemento,pop;
        char funcao[max];
        int i,j=0;
    
                    int p = prioridade('a','b');
                    printf("%d",p);
                            scanf("%[^\n]",funcao);
    
                        for(i=0;i<strlen(funcao);i++){
                           elemento.tipo = funcao[i];
            if(elemento.tipo == '-' || elemento.tipo == '+' || elemento.tipo == '/' || elemento.tipo == '^' || elemento.tipo == '*' || elemento.tipo == '(' || elemento.tipo == ')'){
                        if(pi.topo == 0 || elemento.tipo == '('){
                            empilha(&pi,elemento);
                        }
                        else if(pi.topo == 0 || elemento.tipo == ')'){
                            while(pi.topo>0 && pop.tipo!= '('){
                                    printa(&pi);
                                    desempilha(&pi,&pop);
                                  }
                                  desempilha(&pi,&pop);
                        }else{
                            while(pi.topo > 0){
                                printa(&pi);
                                desempilha(&pi,&pop);
                            }
                            empilha(&pi,elemento);
                        }
                    }else{
                        printf("%c",elemento.tipo);
                    }
                }
                //printf("%c",elemento.tipo);
                while(pi.topo > 0){
                    printa(&pi);
                    desempilha(&pi,&pop);
                }
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Você precisa de uma função que retorna a prioridade do operador. Multiplicação e divisão possuem maior prioridade do que adição e subtração, que por sua vez possuem prioridade maior do que parêntesis. A ideia, quando o operador não for `(` e `)`, é desempilhar da pilha enquanto a prioridade do item no topo da pilha for maior do que a prioridade do elemento atual. Veja [esse artigo](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/InfixPrefixandPostfixExpressions.html) (em inglês) com uma solução em Python. Você está bem perto!

Comment: Sim, eu estou tentando, mano ja fiz umas 10 funcao aqui e não deu certo para comprar as paradinha.

Comment: estou com o código aqui, ta quase pronto, so falta ele comparar as prioridades quando nao precisa ele faz tudo certinho, se quiser da uma olhada no codigo

Comment: Tranforma todos os numeros e simbolos para ASCII, mete por ordem e crescente e transforma de volta.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no tratamento da prioridade das operações. Tenha em mente que uma operação com prioridade menor ou igual não pode estar em cima de uma operação com prioridade maior. Eu confesso que não entendi o propósito da sua função prioridade. Eu recomendo que você construa uma função booleana que receba dois operadores e retorne se o da esquerda tem a prioridade maior ou igual que o da direita. Então, você pode alterar o trecho:

```
while(pi.topo > 0){
         printa(&pi);
         desempilha(&pi,&pop);
}
```

por:

```
while(pi.topo > 0 && checaPrioridade(pi.topo, elemento)){
         printa(&pi);
         desempilha(&pi,&pop);
}
```

Isto deve resolver o problema.